# package and package-lock are not in sync running npm ci

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

I'm currently attempting to deploy my application to Heroku, but in doing so with the frontend I began to run into an issue of:

```
`npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

Attempting to do this locally was showing the same issues (it ran just fine locally, but I can't do the npm ci which is blocking my Heroku deployment).

Did some looking around and came across [Digital Ocean app deployment error: package and package-lock are not in sync running npm ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72599027/digital-ocean-app-deployment-error-package-and-package-lock-are-not-in-sync-run) and the answer there of removing package-lock.json, node-modules, cleaning the npm cache, and adding the engines to package.json helped me narrow things down and now I'm only running into one last issue with the npm ci, which is:

```
Invalid: lock file's typescript@5.3.3 does not satisfy typescript@4.9.5
```

I can't seem to find what is causing this issue and it's not even being defined in my package.json so I'm not sure where it's coming from.

EDIT: I've managed to fix it locally by adding Typescript@4.9.5 directly, however when attempting to do the Heroku deployment I'm still seeing:

```
remote:        npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/material@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @babel/runtime@7.16.7 does not satisfy @babel/runtime@7.23.5
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/base@5.0.0-beta.26 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/core-downloads-tracker@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/system@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/types@7.2.10 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/utils@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @types/react-transition-group@4.4.4 does not satisfy @types/react-transition-group@4.4.10
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: clsx@2.0.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's csstype@3.0.10 does not satisfy csstype@3.1.3
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's react-transition-group@4.4.2 does not satisfy react-transition-group@4.4.5
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: regenerator-runtime@0.14.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @floating-ui/react-dom@2.0.4 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @popperjs/core@2.11.2 does not satisfy @popperjs/core@2.11.8
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: clsx@2.0.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @floating-ui/dom@1.5.3 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @floating-ui/core@1.5.2 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @floating-ui/utils@0.1.6 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/private-theming@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @mui/styled-engine@5.14.20 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: clsx@2.0.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @emotion/cache@11.7.1 does not satisfy @emotion/cache@11.11.0
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @emotion/memoize@0.8.1 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @emotion/sheet@1.1.0 does not satisfy @emotion/sheet@1.2.2
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @emotion/utils@1.0.0 does not satisfy @emotion/utils@1.2.1
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: @emotion/weak-memoize@0.3.1 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: stylis@4.2.0 from lock file
remote:        npm ERR! Invalid: lock file's @types/prop-types@15.7.4 does not satisfy @types/prop-types@15.7.11
remote:        npm ERR! Missing: react-is@18.2.0 from lock file
```

My package file looks as follows
**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "recipe-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "20.9.0",
    "npm": "10.2.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mars/heroku-js-runtime-env": "^3.0.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "notistack": "^2.0.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.jsx --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.15"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried deleting your `package-lock.json` file and re-running `npm i` to regenerate it?

Comment: Since you don't have typescript as a dependency on your package.json, I think two of your dependencies are using a different version of typescript that aren't compatible. Can you provide your package-lock.json generated by npm i ?

Comment: @chill389cc Yeah, there were a lot more mismatches previously and after doing all that it brought it down to just the one in the post

Comment: @Dorian349 Yeah let me try, it went beyond the character limits of both this and pastebin

Comment: @Dorian349 Had to do it through Dropbox, hopefully this works
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/iy0oj1e6b0726h8431m5g/package-lock.json?rlkey=y0c1l1xapkho7z965eg6k80rx&dl=0

Comment: Added transcript directly and that fixed it locally, but I'm actually still seeing a ton of mismatches when doing the Heroku deployment, so I'm not too sure why it would vary there

Comment: Took another look at the console output when doing the Heroku upload and I'm actually noticing:

remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified
\
Even though those are defined in my package.json, so that tells me that it actually seems to be ignoring the real package.json for something else

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running this command locally and then pushing the package-lock file to repo:

```
npm install typescript@4.9.5
```